# Enable partner user to be 'manager' of another partner user

Tags: community, lookup, partner-communities, partner

I am currently using Communities and I am trying to add a partner manager as the 'manager' of another partner user's, user record in Salesforce, using the lookup manager field. I cannot see any partners here. Is it possible to add partners as managers in communities?

Comment: Isn't this something that can be resolved by account-hierarchy and enabling the hierarchy as partners ?

Comment: No, it does not work here either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the Contact and the User.

The Manager field on the Contact has no bearing on the community whatsoever - it's just your CRM data.

(I am assuming you are using Partner Community here).

Depending on the setup of your Community you will have one, two or three Roles created for each Account that is added to the Community - eg Acme will have Acme Partner User, Acme Partner Manager created as Roles.

You need to edit the User record of the "manager" to have the Role of Acme Partner Manager - that way they will be able to see the records that ALL the Acme Partner Users own.

Also look at Super User Access setup to see if that is better than changing the Roles for you.

You could automate this stuff, based on changing the Contact Manager field, but there is no direct link from the Contact record to the user record without querying the users to find which user has this Contact that is linked. Plus the issues of working with the user record, means that you will have to write custom code for this.

Let me know if I need to provide more explanation.